# Android cursor = mydatabase.rawQuery breaks app - signal 11

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I know that similar questions to this have been asked here before, but this is boggling my mind. I have researched this error and it seems to mostly pop up when you are referencing some part of an array outside its bounds or something, but this error ONLY occurs when I run the app on a virtual device with an API below 23. The machine it fails on is a Galaxy Nexus on API 22, however it also fails on a Nexus 4 with API 22. I tested it also on a virtual Nexus 4 with API 23 and it works, every API above this also works. I want my minimum SDK to be even lower but until I resolve this that will be impossible. Below is some code to help you geniuses see what's driving me insane.

(Cursor resultSet is set globally but it doesn't make a difference)
`resultSet = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM words WHERE" + allowRepeats + " frequency >= 0 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",null);` -THIS is the line that breaks no matter what I do.

This code renders to `"SELECT * FROM words WHERE solved < 1 AND frequency >= 0 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"` and this code works on EVERY API above 22, but when running on 22 I get the error "A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x2c in tid 27273 (ics.choicewords)"

Some notes on what I've tried:
I have made sure that the database does exist and like I said it works on other APIs

I have tried setting the cursor just to null and returning empty strings as the result instead of any data, this works fine but of course is not an option

The rawQuery is run inside a loop that cycles 4 times, but taking it out and just running that single line once still breaks with the same error

Error Log:

````
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<Tz>
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<Tz>
W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae9b0880, tid 5080
E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(411)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xae9bf7c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae9bf7c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae839eb0)
E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(411)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21001
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21001
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2186(176KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(12KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 7MB/11MB, paused 9.052ms total 67.508ms
W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
    The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
W/cr_MediaCodecUtil: HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaea6c640: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaea6c640: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae839eb0)
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x2c in tid 4979 (ics.choicewords)```
````

Comment: What is the value of `allowRepeats`? There is no space between `"SELECT * FROM words WHERE"` and `allowRepeats` when you concatenate them. Post the error log.

Comment: `String allowRepeats = " solved <= 1 AND";
        if (swtchAllowRepeats.isChecked())
        {
            allowRepeats = " solved < 1 AND";
        }`

EDIT: Previously, I just had allowRepeats initialized to an empty string as that would work either way, I only initialized it this way to be sure that wasn't the issue but apparently it's not.

Comment: Post the error log.

Comment: Added the error log, but it might be important to note that what's above the last line where the error happens could really be anything. it just always says that last line and fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error a long time ago, so I'm not entirely sure how, but looking back at my old code, it appears the error was created when there were no results that matched the query. I accounted for this afterwards by checking the resultSet count, if it was < 1, I replaced the resultSet with a set of arbitrary values that my app would understand meant no-results. This resolved the issue!